# How to access a variable in a controller function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'd like to be able to access a controller variable inside a function of this controller.

Why is the following code throwing an error into the console instead of showing the input value ?

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.string = "";

    $scope.click = function() { // I've also tried with $scope in parameter
        console.debug(string); // and $scope.string here, same issue
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="string"></input>
    <button ng-click="click()">Click me !</button>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vk4p0c6b/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove $scope from the argument in you click function, and use it inside the function - see below and [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8uaj662/)

```
app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.string = "";

    $scope.click = function() {
        console.debug($scope.string);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach:

```
app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
    this.string = "";
    var that = this;
    $scope.click = function() {
        console.debug(that.string);
    }
});
```

See on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qn47syd2/